# Android: Save History When Launch Second Activty

Tags: android, android-activity, save, history

Created 2 activity with same layout, same button placement, same button id, everything is the same

Example:

Added 3 Buttons in first_activity and second_activity, everything placed on the same place, and with same id, button1, and button2 but the last button, "check" set visibility to gone.

**FIRST ACTIVITY**

Set Background Resource for button1 and button2

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first_activity);
    ..................................................

        //Change button1 drawable to example1.png

    button1 = (Button) ....
    button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.example1);

        //Change button2 drawable to example1.png

    button2 = (Button) ....
    button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.example1);

        //Check Button 

    check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check);
    check.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.example1);

    ..................................................
}
```

button1 onClick

```
public void button1_click (View v){

    //If button2 drawable same as check it will changed to another drawable

    if (button2.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(check.getBackground().getConstantState())){
        button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.example2);
    }
    else {
        button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.example1);
    }
}
```

button2 onClick

```
public void button2_click (View v){
    Intent second_activity=new Intent (getApplicationContext(), second_activity.class);
    startActivity(second_activity); 

        //Calling Second Activity when button2 pressed

    finish(); 

        //Finish First Activity
}
```

**CONDITION :** First pressed button1, button2 drawable changed to example2.png. Second Pressed button2 that will launch second_activity and close first_activity

**MY QUESTION :** How to keep button2 drawable set to example2.png after launch second_activity

I'm using code below in second_activity the same as first_activity

**SECOND ACTIVITY**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
    ..................................................

        //Change button1 drawable to example1.png

    button1 = (Button) ....
    button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.example1);

        //Change button2 drawable to example1.png

    button2 = (Button) ....
    button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.example1);

        //Check Button 

    check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check);
    check.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.example1);

    ..................................................
}
```

Comment: As u r changing only some part of UI in second activity,I would like to suggest u to use `ViewFlipper`.have a look at the docs `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html` for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an "extra" to the Intent that you use to start the second activity. This "extra" could contain information about the state of the buttons. In the `onCreate()` of the second activity, you can examine the information in the "extra" and set the backgrounds of the buttons accordingly.

**EDIT: Add example code**

I would create a boolean variable for each button, indicating the state of the background and add this to each activity, like this:

```
private boolean button1Checked;
private boolean button2Checked;
```

Then, whenever you change the background color, you change the state of the appropriate variable:

```
if (...) {
    button2.setBackgroundResource(...);
    button2Checked = true; // or false, whatever
}
```

Then, when you want to start activity2, you add the state of the 2 buttons as extras to the Intent, like this:

```
Intent intent=new Intent (this, second_activity.class); // use "this" instead of getApplicationContext()
intent.putExtra("button1Checked", button1Checked);
intent.putExtra("button1Checked", button2Checked);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now, in `onCreate()` of the second activity, you recover the state of the buttons from the passed extras, like this:

```
button1 = (Button) ....
button1Checked = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("button1Checked", false);
if (button1Checked) {
    button1.setBackgroundResource(...); // true state
} else {
    button1.setBackgroundResource(...); // false state
}

button2 = (Button) ....
button2Checked = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("button2Checked", false);
if (button2Checked) {
    button2.setBackgroundResource(...); // true state
} else {
    button2.setBackgroundResource(...); // false state
}
```

Hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Also need to create boolean variable in second activity?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to create the boolean variables in each activity. But obviously, by your most recent comment, you got it working. Good.